# Array of hashes each do when certain value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an array of hashes called `rooms` that looks like this:

```
[{:room=>1, :clients=>["Jim K", "Barbara K"], :rooming_request=>"Double"},
 {:room_number=>2, :clients=>["Marcy B"], :rooming_request=>"WTS"},
 {:room_number=>3, :clients=>["Stephanie C", "Stan C"], :rooming_request=>"Twin"},
 {:room_number=>4, :clients=>["Steven W"], :rooming_request=>"SS"},
 {:room_number=>5, :clients=>["Linda W"], :rooming_request=>"SS"},
 {:room_number=>6, :clients=>["Rick M", "Linda M"], :rooming_request=>"Double"},
 {:room_number=>7, :clients=>["Deb M", "William F"], :rooming_request=>"Double"}]
```

And right now, I iterate through it like so:

```
rooms.each do |room|
   room[:room_number]
   room[:clients].join("<br>")
```

Which looks like:

```
1 Jim K
  Barbara K

2 Marcy B

3 Stephanie C
  Stan C

etc..
```

How would I go about only outputting if a certain `rooming_request`?

Such as -

```
rooms.where(rooming_request: "Double").each do |room|
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#select`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select):

```
rooms.select { |room_hash| room_hash[:rooming_request] == 'Double' }
     .each do |room_hash|
  # Do your magic
end
```

Or

```
rooms.each do |room|
  next unless room[:rooming_request] == 'Double'
  # Do your stuff
end
```

Comment: You're a rockstar!